# Return value from Access SQL Select Query

Tags: ms-access

I would like to save the result from the SELECT to a variable, in MS Access.
It should select the most recent offer price from the PriceFeed table where stock symbol in the table matches the selected item from the form comboBox.

```vb
Dim sq2 As Variant
sql = "SELECT PriceFeed.Offer FROM PriceFeed WHERE PriceFeed.StockSymbol =    Me.CBSymbol.Column(1) AND DateTime =(SELECT MAX([PriceFeed.DateTime])FROM PriceFeed)"
DoCmd.RunSQL sq2
```

Comment: Consider [DLookup Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *DMax* and *DLookup*:

```
RecentPrice = DLookup("Offer", "PriceFeed", "StockSymbol = " & Me.CBSymbol.Column(1) & " AND DateTime = DMax('DateTime', 'PriceFeed')")
```

To avoid errors if no CBSymbol has been selected:

```
RecentPrice = DLookup("Offer", "PriceFeed", "StockSymbol = " & Nz(Me.CBSymbol.Column(1), 0) & " AND DateTime = DMax('DateTime', 'PriceFeed')")
```

Comment: Then your combobox is Null. See edited answer, please.